# Limits that require polynom actions?

Tags: limits, polynomials

i have encountered this example one day in the exam
and i could not solve it.

[image]

The tip that professor gave me was

x^3-2x-4 / x-2

But yet i could not understand it, nor did i know
how to start it. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you mean $(x^3-2x-4)/(5x\color{red}{-}10)$?

Comment: no, he said u need to decrees the polynomial level on the upper part of the example, and then you can continue to solve it

Comment: Look at the limit, are you sure you didn't make a typo? Otherwise it would trivially evaluate to 0. Perhaps it should be $5x-10$ in the denominator in stead?

Answer (score 0):

(This supposes that you mean $x-5$ in the denominator otherwise the limit would be trivial, and your prof's hint would not make sense)

Both polynomials are divisible by $x-2$, namely

$$x^3-2x-4=(x^2+2x+2)(x-2)$$

and

$$5x-10=5(x-2)$$

So the limit reduces to:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{x^3-2x-4}{5x-10}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{(x^2+2x+2)(x-2)}{5(x-2)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{x^2+2x+2}{5}=2$$

Side note: Since $x-2$ divides both of the polynomials, they are both zero at $x=2$. This means we could also have used L'hopital:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{x^3-2x-4}{5x-10}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{3x^2-2}{5}=2$$

Comment: This helps a lot, what i don't understand is.

How did you divide the numerator with (x-2), can you show me the steps cause i don't know how to do that. x^3-2x-4 / x-2

Comment: @John Try multiplying out $(x^2+2x+2)(x-2)$. You will see that it is indeed $x^3-2x-4$. Another way of saying this is that $\frac{x^2-2x-4}{x-2}=x^2+2x+2$ (divide by $x-2$ on both sides). The trick is to actually find the factorization, which can be done by [polyomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)